# Navigate to another View after OK Alert Button click without using segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertaction

On click ok button I want ot redirect user to another controller without using segue.

```
   // here is my alert

   [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Profile details updated successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
```

Have any idea please share.

Comment: `UIAlertView` has been deprecated and replaced with `UIAlertController` which is a lot more flexible in adding actions to the buttons. You should use that instead.

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code it works for you

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                 message:@"Profile details updated successfully."
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                            {
                                //put your navigation code here
                               // *** THIS IS WHERE YOU NAVIGATE TO LOGIN
                                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; 
                            }];


UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               //Put code for cancel here

                           }];

   [alert addAction:ok];
   [alert addAction:cancel];
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer, everyone else posted deprecated methods..  this is still wrong though, see my edit to this answer

Comment: Agreed. This is the only correct answer. (With @MSU_Bulldog edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 0) //**Here is your ok button index**
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   LoginViewController *controller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"]; 
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
 }
}
```

As above method is **deprecated** in **ios 8** ,For that you need to use ***alertcontroller*** instead ***alertview*** as follow

```
  UIAlertController * alertController=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"App name"
                             message:@"Update success"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                  LoginViewController *controller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"]; 
                  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
                }];

 [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
 [alertController addAction:okAction];
 [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
 UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationController"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

implement alertview delegate:

```
@interface firstviewcontroller : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{
}
```

set your code: delegate= self in alertview;

```
-[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Profile details updated successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
```

Delegate method for alertview:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ViewController *controller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer actually my mistake was i was not setting delegate = self @bhadresh